# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null for Kotlin and WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I am trying to populate my WebView with custom HTML string and trying to show progress when it is not loaded, and hide it when finished.

Here is my code:

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, presentation.content, "text/html", "utf-8", null)

webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

  override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
    webViewProgressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE
    webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
  }

  override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView, url: String) {
    super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
    webViewProgressBar.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE
    webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }
}
```

I am getting this error, which is not pointing to any line of my code:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter favicon
at com.hidglobal.tmt.app.mobiBadge.ui.presentation.PresentationActivity$showPresentation$1.onPageStarted(PresentationActivity.kt)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:215)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:20)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: It says that parameter `favicon` in `onPageStarted` function is defined as not-null, but it received null. So, you can define it as `Bitmap?`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### TL; DR

The system passes a `null` `favicon` but it is defined as a non-nullable Kotlin type. You can fix it by changing the signature to `favicon: Bitmap?` to make it nullable.

### Full response

The issue is that method `onPageStarted` is called (by the system) passing a `null` value for the `favicon` parameter. This may happen when there is some Kotlin code that is interoperating with Java code (by default you should get nullable objects).

Any platform type (e.g. any objects coming from Java) can be `null`, because Java has no special notation to tell that something can or cannot be `null`. For that reason when you use platform types in Kotlin you can choose to either:

- use it "as-is"; the consequence in such case is that (from documentation)

  > Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety guarantees for them are the same as in Java

  Hence you may get `NullPointerException`s, like in the following example:

  ```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val array = Vector<String>() // we need to Vector as it's not mapped to a Kotlin type
      array.add(null)
      val retrieved = array[0]
      println(retrieved.length) // throws NPE
  }
  ```
- cast it to a specific type (either nullable or non-nullable); in this case the Kotlin compiler will treat it as a "normal" Kotlin type. Example:

  ```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val array = Vector<String>() // we need to Vector as it's not mapped to a Kotlin type
      array.add("World")
      val retrieved: String = array[0] // OK, as we get back a non-null String
      println("Hello, $retrieved!") // OK
  }
  ```

  However, this will throw an exception if you enforce a non-nullable type but then get back `null`. Example:

  ```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val array = Vector<String>() // we need to Vector as it's not mapped to a Kotlin type
      array.add(null)
      val retrieved: String = array[0] // we force a non-nullable type but get null back -> throws NPE
      println("Hello, World!") // will not reach this instruction
  }
  ```

  In such case you can "play it safe" and enforce the variable to be nullable – this will never fail, but could make the code harder to read:

  ```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val array = Vector<String>() // we need to Vector as it's not mapped to a Kotlin type
      array.add(null)
      val retrieved: String? = array[0] // OK since we use a nullable type
      println("Hello, $retrieved!") // prints "Hello, null!"
  }
  ```

You can use the latter example in your code to cope with the `bitmap` being null:

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, i was converting code from Java and didn't notice this obvious problem. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can see also the problem, but my progressBar is not appearing at all. Is this right place for define such case for progressBar?

Comment: How long does it take for the HTML page to load? Maybe that's so quick that your progress bar has no time to disappear/reappear, which might be the case if you load some local content

Answer (score 55):

I have the same problem.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter favicon
    at com.haoyong.szzc.module.share.view.activity.WebActivity$MyWebViewClient.onPageStarted(WebActivity.kt:0)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:495)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:122)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5313)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1116)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:809)
```

I just do it as follows:
**change**

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }
```

**to**

```
 override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }
```

Because it is not allowed to use the null parameter in the Kotlinlang. just change the Bitmap to Bitmap? Then it will work well. Hope this can help the other people.

Comment: super nice solution

Comment: But I have 300+ method. How to do that easily?

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon find and replace all at once.

Comment: Perfect Answer.

Comment: Good solution very nice.. indeed !!

Answer (score -1):

```
private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(getActivity()));
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    //Multi touch detected
                    return true;
                }

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        // save the x
                        m_downX = event.getX();
                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        // set x so that it doesn't move
                        event.setLocation(m_downX, event.getY());
                    }
                    break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        Context context;

        public MyWebChromeClient(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

    }
```

Inside on create---

initWebView()

```
binding.webView.loadUrl(urlName)
```

Just try it for smooth web view URL load.