# Kotlin - IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I am passing data to some fragment in bundle and while receiving it throws the exception. This error occurs while restoring Fragment's state.

Error occurs in *Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull* when *createFromParcel* is called. This happen with all non-nullable fields in Model.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.b.h.b, parameter realtorImageUrl
   at com.android.app.ui.common.model.Property.(Unknown Source:16)
   at com.android.app.ui.common.model.Property$Creator.createFromParcel(Unknown Source:637)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2797)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2691)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3058)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.getInt(BaseBundle.java:961)
   at me.yokeyword.fragmentation.SupportFragmentDelegate.onCreate(SourceFile:93)
   at me.yokeyword.fragmentation.SupportFragment.onCreate(SourceFile:48)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(SourceFile:2331)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1386)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1759)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1827)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(SourceFile:3244)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(SourceFile:3194)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(SourceFile:1444)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onCreate(SourceFile:1415)
   at me.yokeyword.fragmentation.SupportFragment.onCreate(SourceFile:47)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(SourceFile:2331)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1386)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1759)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1827)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(SourceFile:3244)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(SourceFile:3194)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(SourceFile:184)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:355)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:84)
   at me.yokeyword.fragmentation.SupportActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:38)
   at com.android.app.ui.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:47)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Property.kt

```
@Parcelize
data class Property(
    ...
    @Json(name = "RealtorImageUrl")
    val realtorImageUrl: String
    ...
) : Parcelable
```

Kotlin 1.1.4, Android Extensions plugin provides Parcelable implementation generator using @Parcelize.

PropertyListFragment.kt

```
override fun showPropertyDetails(property: Property) {
    (parentFragment as PropertySearchResultFragment).start(
        PropertyDetailsFragment.newInstance(property)
    )
}
```

PropertyDetailsFragment.kt

```
class PropertyDetailsFragment{
    ...
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(property: Property) = PropertyDetailsFragment().withArgs {
            putParcelable(INT_EXTRA_PROPERTY, property)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

What do I need to do to fix the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323455/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-for

Comment: No, you can't be sure. error is that your `realtorImageUrl` you specified as non-null gets null for some reason. you might took it as **lateinit var** which is still not initialized when accessing.

Comment: @NileshRathod The link which you have provided is the different issue. When accessing java classes in kotlin all the variables are null so you need to use "?" when accessing any java variable. I don't know how parameter in model got null.

Comment: Um, you say `I know realtorImageUrl is not null` but clearly it can be null.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I mean to say data is not null when it's displayed. I want to know the reason why it got null.

Comment: 1) how do you define `realtorImageUrl`? 2) how do you interact with `realtorImageUrl`? in what method (or override method)?

Comment: Please post the code on how you interact with `realtorImageUrl` and how you setting/retrieving it from the parcelable

Comment: @ariefbayu I have added more details.

Comment: @EricMartori I have added more details.

Comment: Have you check the `Property` is properly set and that `realtorImageUrl` is not null before putting it as an extra property? It seems that you are getting a null value in it which with you defenitions could only happen when you are creating the `Property`instance.

Comment: How do you call `showPropertyDetails(property: Property)`? It is very possible that `showPropertyDetails()` is called before `property` / `realtorImageUrl` is being set. This is the problem with `lateinit`, you have to make sure the variable is already set and is set in proper order.

Comment: Did you try to set property as nullable - `val realtorImageUrl: String?` ?

Comment: The problem is may be with Json parsing, Whenever JsonResponse does not have RealtorImageUrl, it will consider it as null

Answer (score 3):

Since the `realtorImageUrl` is defined not null, so kotlin does not permit to set it to null. Therefore the only possible way to do that is to set the null value by reflection. Json helper libraries are based on annotation processing and using  reflection for setting value to the fields, so the problem definitely comes from them.

- First of all, I highly recommend you to use google `Gson`.
- Second, be sure that the json string is not null or empty after configuration changes.
- Third, be sure that you are using `moshi-kotlin` (not simple `moshi`) in dependencies and adding an instance of `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` to the `moshi` builder.

**build.gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0'
```

**Test:**

```
val json = "{\"RealtorImageUrl\": \"http://www.gstatic.com/tv/thumb/persons/667736/667736_v9_ba.jpg\"}"

val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()) // com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
        .build()

val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Property::class.java) as JsonAdapter<Property>
val property = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json) as Property

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, PropertyDetailsFragment.newInstance(property))
        .commit()
```

It is better to use `withArguments` from [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) to put arguments for the fragment:

**PropertyDetailsFragment.kt:**

```
class PropertyDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val property = arguments?.getParcelable(KEY_EXTRA_PROPERTY) as Property
        val realtorImageUrl = property.realtorImageUrl
    }

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_EXTRA_PROPERTY = "KEY_EXTRA_PROPERTY"

        fun newInstance(property: Property) = PropertyDetailsFragment().withArguments(
                KEY_EXTRA_PROPERTY to property
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh: What is a library with `@Json` annotation? I have tested it using google `Gson` and no problem happened in restoring fragment state like phone rotation.

Comment: I am using Moshi library. Is there any difference when using Anko library?

Comment: I think the problem comes from moshi library. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Can you explain why there is problem with moshi library?

Comment: If you add `moshi` library instead of `moshi-kotlin` or don't add `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` in moshi builder, it fills null in json model variable.

Comment: I am still confused. Error occurs when calling createFromParcel method for recreating Parcelable object.

Comment: Ok, you have defined the `realtorImageUrl` not null and kotlin does not permit to set it null. The only possible way to do that is to set the null value by reflection. As annotation processor json libraries set values to the fields using reflection, so the problem definitely comes from them.

Comment: Tell me about two points which I said please (moshi-kotlin and KotlinJsonAdapterFactory). Did you check them?

Comment: Sir, what's the problem with the solution that OP has, that's the question.

Comment: It's production code and not reproducible so I can't use other solution moshi-kotlin and KotlinJsonAdapterFactory. Strage part is that I have got many models of these type and passing them in Fragment but I am getting error only in this Property model.

Comment: According to https://github.com/square/moshi#kotlin, its needed to make moshi work properly in kotlin. I think unfortunately we have no choice in your described situation :-|

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might not be the perfect solution but it can solve your issue. You can make your property nullable and just add a null check whenever you access them.

Just initialize you variable like this

Property.kt

```
@Parcelize
data class Property(
    ...
    @Json(name = "RealtorImageUrl")
    val realtorImageUrl: String
    ...
) : Parcelable
```

PropertyListFragment.kt

```
override fun showPropertyDetails(property: Property?) {
    (parentFragment as PropertySearchResultFragment).start(
        PropertyDetailsFragment.newInstance(property)
    )
}
```

And in **PropertyDetailsFragment.kt**

```
class PropertyDetailsFragment{
    ...
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(property: Property?) = PropertyDetailsFragment().withArgs {
            property?.let{
                putParcelable(INT_EXTRA_PROPERTY, property)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is not nullity of `property`, `realtorImageUrl` makes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can u try using @field:Json(name = "RealtorImageUrl") and check if it works then?

Also, check if you have added proper factory KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()

```
 val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```