# Kotlin exception: Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting the exception at line `if (text.startsWith(prefix))`. How come? What the hell is going on here?

Here's my code.

CustomEditText.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.EditText

class CustomEditText : EditText {

    private val prefix: String = "AS"

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    override fun onSelectionChanged(selStart: Int, selEnd: Int) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd)
        if (text.startsWith(prefix)) {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.myapplication.CustomEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
2019-11-28 15:58:46.623 11608-11608/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 11608
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.myapplication.CustomEditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2821)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2929)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6678)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:830)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.myapplication.CustomEditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.myapplication.CustomEditText
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2929)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6678)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:830)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter prefix
        at kotlin.text.StringsKt__StringsKt.startsWith(Unknown Source:7)
        at kotlin.text.StringsKt__StringsKt.startsWith$default(Strings.kt:749)
        at com.example.myapplication.CustomEditText.onSelectionChanged(CustomEditText.kt:21)
        at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:9662)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:12121)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1272)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:773)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:672)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
2019-11-28 15:58:46.624 11608-11608/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
        at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:312)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5532)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5400)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:113)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1652)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:80)
        at com.example.myapplication.CustomEditText.<init>(CustomEditText.kt:13)
            ... 26 more
```

Comment: What is above these lines in stack trace? I have a guess, but it would depend on `<init>` appearing there.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov added full stack trace.

Comment: EditText `getText` is nullable. Add null check while invoking `text.startsWith(..)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null for Kotlin and WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323455/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JVM (including Android) superclass constructor body runs before subclass field initializers. Since you can see the line

```
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1652)
```

in the stack trace, the problem happens inside `TextView`'s constructor and `prefix` hasn't been initialized yet.

Since you have the same `prefix` for any `CustomEditText`, a simple fix would be to move it into companion object, maybe make it [`const`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants). Otherwise you could e.g. use [`by lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy).

Of course, we are inside

```
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:113)
```

too, so maybe `text` is still null as well (you'd have to check implementation)...

Answer (score 0):

Use let function with safecall(?.) operator when you are such kind of operation. 
Using Let keyword, the block will excecute when it get non-null values.

usage:

```
text?.let {
    // run this code if your 'text' is not null ..
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question is how `prefix` (not `text`) can be `null` in the first place

Comment: @Tenfour04 The message clearly says `prefix` is null.